# UIButton center position doesn't update with rotation

Tags: ios, xcode, rotation, uibutton

I have a program that dynamically generates UIButtons in the center of
the screen with push of another button.
The buttons are not updating the x-coordinates when I rotate the device.

Here is my code for creating buttons:

```
- (IBAction)createButton:(UIButton *)sender {

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
       [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(doSomething:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    button.frame = CGRectMake(self.xCoord,self.yOffset,100.0,120.0);

    [self.view addSubview:button];

    _yOffset = _yOffset+130;     
}
```

The XCoord and self.yOffset were set in viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.yOffset = 109;
    self.xCoord = self.view.bounds.size.width/2-50;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The coordinates of the button in your code are fixed once they've been added to the view. If you want to update the frame of the buttons when the screen rotates, you'll need to trigger the repositioning of the buttons when the screen rotates.

AutoLayout in a storyboard makes this easier (if you just want a button to appear then you can add it in a storyboard and change its `hidden` property from `NO` to `YES` when the other button is pressed --  this won't be helpful if you want to add an arbitrary number of buttons, although you could have a hidden placeholder view that you use as a positioning reference)

Comment: Thank you so much. How would I trigger respositioning with rotation if I chose to do it dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the buttons x-position, you need to add Auto Layout constraints. There are a couple ways to do this programmatically. You can use the NSLayoutConstraint object directly or use Auto Layout's Visual Format Language. For more info, see [Apple's documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AutoLayoutinCode/AutoLayoutinCode.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH11-SW1)